# How do I avoid my objects jumping to the other side, when I change rotation direction?

Tags: unity, c#, rotation

I implemented an algorithm for circular movement:

```
angle += Time.deltaTime * speed;

float x = (float)( Mathf.Cos(angle) * radius);
float y = (float)( Mathf.Sin(angle) * radius);
```

I want the player to be able to change the direction of the movement between clockwise and counter-clockwise.

If I do it like this:

```
if(clockwise)
        transform.position = new Vector3(-x, y);
    else
        transform.position = new Vector3(x, y);
```

it generally works, but my object jumps to the other side of the object it's rotating around. This makes sense, to me, because the x-coordinate changes. How do I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the provided example, your increasing `angle` over time, based off `speed` and `Time.deltaTime`. However, when you mean to change direction by providing a positive or negative value, your actually *inverting* the angle.

[image: Providing the angle as a negative gives the inverted angle.]

---

Instead, you should be changing your `angle` value *over time*, based on the direction.

```
if(clockwise)
{
    angle -= Time.deltaTime * speed;
}
else
{
    angle += Time.deltaTime * speed;
}
```

---

An alternate solution, if you do not have any other use for the `clockwise` boolean, would be to turn it into an integer that should always be `1` for counter-clockwise, or `-1` for clockwise. This only simplifies your code to a minor degree.

```
int clockwise;

// ...

angle -= Time.deltaTime * speed * clockwise;

// .. and depending on how you intend to set direction..

void SetClockwise()
{
    clockwise = -1;
}

void SetCounterClockwise()
{
    clockwise = 1;
}

void ChangeRotationDirection
{
    clockwise *= -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to decrease angle if you want to make the object go in the other direction.

Comment: Damn stupid me!
Of course that is the solution!
Thanks so much!

Comment: @Steffen make sure to mark the answer correct if it helped your problem